# How to save information on a File and Download it in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a Template that shows some information about some customer´s bill. This is how i show that information:

```
<table id="items">
    <tr>
        <th class="tipo">Tipo de Factura</th>
        <th class="descripcion">Descripcion</th>
        <th>Precio</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item-row">
        <td><div><textarea>{{fact.tipo_Factura}}</textarea></div></td>
        <td class="description"><textarea>{{fact.descripcion}}</textarea></td>
        <td><span class="price">$ {{fact.importe_sin_iva}}</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="totales">
    <tr>
        <td class="total-line">Subtotal</td>
        <td class="total-value"><div id="subtotal">$ {{fact.importe_sin_iva}}</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="total-line">Iva</td>
        <td class="total-value"><div id="total">$ {{iva}}</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td  class="total-line">Precio Total</td>
        <td class="total-value"><textarea id="paid">$ {{total}}</textarea></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

A simple table with CSS. I manage to send this template as an HtmlEmail with no problems. But now the users need to download this template into their computers as a proof that they paid. So that´s the question: Do i have to save this template with the information (in the same way i save everything in a ".email" when i send the email) in a file and then make the users download that or is there another way to do it that i´m not seeing?
The format that they should download this are PDF or Excel. Thank you.

I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Hello I would recommend the following resource http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something similar with bills at work,

> How did I solve the download problem?

Well we use a paid system named [cloudfiles](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/files/?cm_mmc=PPCCA-_-Google-_-broad-_-online%20storage%20cloud) as you can see it's a cloud storage.

What you can do is to create a PDF with either [reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/) or [xhtml2pdf](http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/) upload it to cloudfiles, then you save the url in a model and create a view for downloading the file.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. One question, i can not use a paid system like cloudfiles, so i have to find another way to do the same. Ant ideas?. Thanks

Comment: You can save pdfs in media folder for development and when you decide to put your app in production you can use cloudfiles

Comment: Thanks. i´m posting another question because now it has to be downloaded as Excel file...damn you Users...Thanks for the answers

Comment: For excel is the same just use a library for create excel files

Comment: Yeah well the thing is that the company doesn´t want to pay the cloudfiles storage so i have to find another way to save the file and make the download in the page. Thank you